# Strange, Why when changing the doors colors it's changing it for all the doors and not each door individual?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to empty GameObject using the ExecuteAlways so it will work also in edit mode and also runtime mode :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();
    public List<bool> DoorsLockState = new List<bool>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Doors.Count == 0 || DoorsLockState.Count == 0)
        {
            Doors = FindObjectsOfType<HoriDoorManager>().ToList();
            DoorsLockState = new bool[Doors.Count].ToList();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < DoorsLockState.Count; i++)
        {
            Doors[i].lockState = DoorsLockState[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And this script is attached to each door also in this script I'm using the ExecuteAlways attribute :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DoorHori door1;
    public DoorHori door2;
    public bool lockState;

    private List<Material> doorsRenderers = new List<Material>();

    private void Start()
    {
        doorsRenderers.Add(door1.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial);
        doorsRenderers.Add(door2.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial);
        doorsRenderers[0].shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");
        doorsRenderers[1].shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (lockState == false)
        {
            if (door1 != null)
            {
                door1.OpenDoor();
            }

            if (door2 != null)
            {
                door2.OpenDoor();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(lockState == false)
        {
            doorsRenderers[0].SetColor("_MainColor", Color.green);
        }
        else
        {
            doorsRenderers[0].SetColor("_MainColor", Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm changing the state of the flag in the first script in the List DoorsLockState it's not changing the colors of the doors only one flag change the color for all the doors.

It does change the lock state but I want that each door also will change the color according to the lock state. Lock = Red Unlock = Green.

The DoorHori class :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorHori : MonoBehaviour {

    public float translateValue;
    public float easeTime;
    public OTween.EaseType ease;
    public float waitTime;

    private Vector3 StartlocalPos;
    private Vector3 endlocalPos;

    private void Start(){
        StartlocalPos = transform.localPosition;    
        gameObject.isStatic = false;
    }

    public void OpenDoor(){
        OTween.ValueTo( gameObject,ease,0.0f,-translateValue,easeTime,0.0f,"StartOpen","UpdateOpenDoor","EndOpen");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    private void UpdateOpenDoor(float f){       
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection( new Vector3( 1,0,0));
        transform.localPosition = StartlocalPos + pos*f;

    }

    private void UpdateCloseDoor(float f){      
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection( new Vector3( -f,0,0)) ;

        transform.localPosition = endlocalPos-pos;

    }

    private void EndOpen(){
        endlocalPos = transform.localPosition ;
        StartCoroutine( WaitToClose());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitToClose(){

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        OTween.ValueTo( gameObject,ease,0.0f,translateValue,easeTime,0.0f,"StartClose","UpdateCloseDoor","EndClose");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: door1 & door2 is 2 doors? could you show DoorHori Class too?

Comment: @Frenchy Added it to my question.

Comment: Probably because the doors share materials

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the sharedMaterial which is shared between all your doors

```cs
doorsRenderers.Add(door1.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial);
//Notice the ".shadredMaterial" at the end here
```

Instead of the instance of a material.

by using `doorsRenderers[0].shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");` you are also accessing the shader directly, meaning that any changes made to it will reflect on every instance of that material.

`doorsRenderers[0].SetColor("_MainColor", Color.green);` also accesses the Material and the underlying shader directly, instead of the material instance (By default Unity will create an instance of a material when a material is edited in runtime)

There is two ways you can go about fixing this:

- Use two different materials (one red, one green) and swap out the material for the one required.
- Get the GameObjects' Renderer instead of the (shared)material, and apply the colour change by using the `Renderer.material.color` property instead. This will create a material instance, changing only that instance's colour.

Solution two would look something like this:

```cs
private List<Renderer> doorsRenderers = new List<Renderer>();

private void Start()
{
    doorsRenderers.Add(door1.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>());
    doorsRenderers.Add(door2.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>());
}

private void ChangeDoorColour()
{
    if(lockState == false)
    {
        doorsRenderers[0].material.color = Color.green;
    }
    else
    {
       doorsRenderers[0].material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

As an aside: You set the material colour of your door every frame by doing it in an update loop, this isn't a very good thing to do and should only be done when the state of doors change. So I put it in a seperate function `ChangeDoorColour()` that should only be called when the state of the door changes (so probably in an `OpenDoor()` and `CloseDoor()` method).

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to change the doors color when the door is open or close but when I change the flags in the first script DoorsLockManager according to the doors lock state. If for example in the inspector I set door 7  flag to false either in runtime or edit mode change in real time the lock state and the door color.  The idea is to set the doors colors according to the lock state not if the door is open or close.

Comment: @AbrahamKrim The code for changing the colour would stay the same `doorsRenderers[0].material.color = Color.<your colour>;`, Just call that code when the flag changes then

Answer (score 0):

If you share the same material and change the color in shader it will change all, better to have two materials and apply them accordingly.

Have two materials one for lock one for unlock.
Have a reference to these colors in the script ie (set in inspector)

```cs
public Material greenMat, redMat;
```

When you want it to be unlocked

```cs
door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = greenMat;
```

Locked

```cs
door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = redMat;
```

Comment: Thanks for edit Remy, I made this post on my phone this morning and the option to format code wasn't there *shrug*